# Modal doesn't play animation twice on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal to view pictures which plays the animation only the first time on Firefox. When I open it first time, it works, but when I open it the second time, it doesn't play the animation. It works on Chrome tho.

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e8/2e/cc/e82ecc7ea98248bfa8161dcfcef2974a.jpg" id="postimage"></img>

 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 999999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
}
#postimage:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 720px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity:0.0}
    to {opacity:1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity:0.0}
    to {opacity:1}
}

.modal-content {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.8s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 1.8s;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #787878;
}
```

**JS**

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var img = document.getElementById('postimage');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("modalImage");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fdfu0qkf/)

Comment: @kodecount for what purpose?

Comment: @kodecount Well it doesn't work. I have tried it.

Comment: The problem is, it will animate again on firefox if it wasn't fully animated. If the animation went to the end, it won't animate again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

and updating the `.modal-content` with:

```
  -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.8s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
```

`-moz-` is specifically for Firefox as is `-webkit-` is for Chrome or Opera. Found this on [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

[`transition-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) effects acceleration of the animation so the speed can adjust with over various duration

[`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) is the number of times an animation cycle will play then stop

[`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) effects how the animation applies styles to the target

Comment: That did the trick! Could you provide some explanation please?

Comment: @Mirakurun Updated the answer.